# Android 4.0 and HTML5 History API

Tags: android, html

Android 3.0 and 4.0 does not support the HTML5 History API (http://caniuse.com/#search=history).
Is there any reason for dropping the support since Android 2.2 and 2.3 supported it?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they missed updating the URL when webkit internally changes it. The 3.0 browser seems to be a complete (mostly at least) rewrite of the 2.3.3 browser.

I reported this to Androids bug tracker at least: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23979